# How to call multiple functions inside another function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have these functions in Haskell:

```
 type World = [String]

 look :: World -> IO World
 look w = do
   putStrLn $ "You are here " ++ show w
   return w

 test w = do
      words <- fmap words getLine
      case words of
        ("quit":_) -> return ()
        ("look":_) -> do w' <- area w'; describe w'
        ("remove":item:_) -> do w' <- removeItem item w; loop w'
        _ -> do putStrLn "Wrong input"; test w

area::String->String
area place =
  return place

describe:: String ->String
describe place =
  case place of
    "usa" -> putStrLn "It is usa"
    "uk" -> putStrLn "It is uk"
    "aur" -> putStrLn "It is aus"

main = do
  let world0 = ["ht", "alt"]
  let place = ["usa"]
  area place
  print place
  test world0
```

In the line

```
("look":_) -> do w' <- area w'; describe w'
```

I want to call the "area" function that returns a place entered in main and the `describe` function to return the description for that place. How can I do that?

Comment: Here is a simple adventure game written in Haskell which might help with program organization: [link](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/cis554-2012/Pages/spider-game-in-haskell.html)

Comment: Shouldn't `area` and `describe` have the types `String -> IO String` and `String -> IO ()` respectively?  You're using `return` and `putStrLn` in these functions, so they have to return a monadic value

Answer (score 2):

In this case your world consists of *two* items of state:

- where you are, and
- what items you have

so `type World = [String]` isn't going to work. You'll need something like:

```
type World = (String, [String])  -- (where, items)
-- or:
data World = World { where_ :: String, items_ :: [String] }
```

and now functions like `removeItem`, `describe` have to be reworked.

For example, suppose we have `type World = (String,[String])`. Then `describe` would go like:

```
describe :: World -> IO ()
describe (place,_) =
  case place of
    "usa" -> ...
    "uk" -> ...
    ...other cases...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain state between the two functions (`main` and `test`), you may use an [`IORef`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-IORef.html) for this.

```
test w ref = do
  -- when you need to read it:
  place <- readIORef ref

i_am_at = writeIORef

main = do
  let world0 = ["ht", "alt"]
  let place = ["usa"]
  ref <- newIORef place -- creates the ref with initial value
  i_am_at ref place -- needs reference
  print place
  test world0 ref
```

But, this goes totally in the wrong direction. It's not Haskell's idiomatic way of doing things. Essentialy, you are reproducing imperative code in a functional language.

Try to refactor your code in a way that you do not need mutable variables, building a State Machine can be a good start.